# TFS 2010 - Annotate Class Files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Within `TFS 2010` there is the functionality to `Annotate` a class / page so that it shows where different pieces of code have been changed, along with who changed them, the date and the change set.

So my question, which is hopefully a relatively straight forward one, is: Can this be filtered to a date range, work item ID or user?  Or would a separate report be needed to provide this functionality?  I am mainly interested in the ability to do this within `Visual Studio 2012` and not so much a report, as it would help with our release proceedure in development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotate shows who wrote (or last changed) each line of code.  So restricting it to a date range would fundamentally change the way it worked.  VS/TFS don't provide any ability to customize how Annotate works.

You could always create your own Visual Studio add-in that provided this functionality.

Comment: Do you know if there is any other known way check what has changed if I was looking for any changes within a short period of time?  I know I can use the compare previous functionality, but that requires selecting each check in.

Comment: You could select all the changsets in question, then do a roll-back on all of them.  It will put pending changes in your local workspace to roll back all changes, you can use that to do your review, then just Undo when done.